# How to get this array structure in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I use Laravel 8 and Vue3, and I want to get the array structure like this:

[image]

I have 3 table.

**Quiz table**

```
Schema::create('quizzes', function (Blueprint $table) { 
           $table->id();
           $table->foreignId('sub_course_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
           $table->string('question');
           $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Answers table**

```
  Schema::create('quiz_answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('quiz_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('answer');
        $table->boolean('correct_answer');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Sub Course table**

```
 Schema::create('sub_courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->foreignId('course_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('url');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I tried it with query:

```
  $quizzes = DB::table('sub_courses')
            ->select('quiz_answers.quiz_id', 'question', 'answer', 'correct_answer')
            ->join('quizzes', 'sub_courses.id', '=', 'quizzes.sub_course_id')
            ->join('quiz_answers', 'quizzes.id', '=', 'quiz_answers.quiz_id')
            ->get();
        return $quizzes;
```

And get this structure.

[image]

Comment: This is what you are looking for [Elequont Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

Answer (score 0):

try to fill the two dimensional array using data